# Mongoose: Pushing items into an array which is a property of an embedded document

Tags: mongoose

Could you please take a look at this code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Ok, I have a schema:

```
var Account = new Schema({
     username: String,
     votes:[
       {                                            
         resId: String,                                 
         upvoted:[String]                                                           
       }
     ]                                                                          
 });
```

I'm trying to push an item into **upvoted**

```
var resId = 'a';
var id = 'b';
var commentId = 'c';

users.update({'_id':id, 'resId': resId},                
{
     '$push': {'votes.$.upvoted': commentId}
});
```

However, it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the result of this update query?

Comment: "resId" should be "votes.resId" in update query

Comment: Yay! Thank you, good sir! It works!